# div into a js button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` that I have formatted very carefully to look nice, and I need to make it have the functionality of a [button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: what do you mean by "functionality of a button"???

Comment: replace `div` with `button`

Comment: Nisal Edu has given me all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give that div tag a onclick function as follows.

```js
function myfns() {
    console.log("Clicked")
}
```

```html
<div id="btn" onclick="myfns()">Click</div>
```

Comment: This would not work for screen readers or keyboard users.

Answer (score 1):

First recommendation is to use a `<button>` instead. You can style that however you want as well. If that is not an option for some reason, you'll have to do a few different things to create a proper button out of a div element (to ensure that it works with keyboard and screen readers).

- Add click handler. Eg `btn.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);`
- Add enter key handler. Eg `btn.addEventListener('keyup', keyHandler);`
- Add button role. `role="button"`
- Add it to tab order: `tabindex="0"`

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

buttons.forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
  
  btn.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('keyup');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" role="button" tabindex="0">My Button</div>

<div class="btn" role="button" tabindex="0">My Button</div>

<div class="btn" role="button" tabindex="0">My Button</div>
```

Comment: He is asking for the div not buttons.

Comment: He is asking for a div to have functionality of a button. Button has more functionality than click handler. And I'd argue that most developers probably won't their app to work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByID("#divID").addEventListenet('click',()=>{
//write your logic
})
```

handle all button event similarly
e.g. *doubleclick* etc

Comment: this would not work for keyboard or screen readers though.

Comment: It all the depend on the use case. He doesnt have that requirement.

Comment: Based on the question I'd say he does. He is not asking for adding a click handler to a div. He is saying "make it have the functionality of a button" which would include all functionality of a button I'd say.

Answer (score -1):

Like if you have `div`

```
 <div class="demo" >
    ....
    </div>
```

And If you are using `javascript`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0]
        .addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            // do something
    });
```

using `jquery` u can do like

```
$(".demo").click(function(){
//do something
});
```

Comment: This does not give the div the functionality of a button. A button has more than just a click handler. A button also works for keyboard users, but your solution doesn't. A button also works for screen reader users, but your solution doesn't.

Comment: ok cool than not used mine :) simple